# Ensuring C++ template does not compile with missing functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `template<typename T> Foo` that uses certain functions of `T`. However, it turns out that the code can compile even without `T` having all the requisite member functions. An example follows.

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    T t;
    int foo() {
        return t.foo();
    }

    int bar() {
        return t.bar();
    }
};

struct baz {
    int foo() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<baz> x;
    return x.foo();
}
```

How can I ensure that the code does not compile if the `T` does not provide all the necessary functions? I know this can be done if I use a base class that contains all the inheritances and derive from that. However, I will really appreciate if this can be done with templates without too much of additional code.

I am using gcc 4.8.2 on Linux.

Comment: when the code compiles, the missing functions can hardly be *technically* necessary. in what sense are they necessary?

Comment: If you want to play with some upcoming C++ features, you can try [concepts](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s).

Comment: They are not "necessary" in the sense of running the code. But it would be nice since sometimes I forget to add a function to `T` and then it is not caught until much later when that function is actually used.

Comment: If you want to try out concepts without using new C++ features, see [Boost.ConceptCheck](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)

Comment: @Mankarse, can you provide some example code?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: They are necessary in the sense that allowing the code to compile without them introduces the possibility of future problems caused by the implementation of `Foo` changing. C++ is a statically typed language, and one advantage of that is that it should be possible to enforce (or at least, strongly encourage) forward and backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

In order to require that a type is a class type with certain accessible member functions, simply refer to them. E.g. in each constructor of `Foo` you can say

```
Foo()
{
    (void) sizeof( decltype( t.foo() ) );
    (void) sizeof( decltype( t.bar() ) );
}
```

The above is a little more than required for your example, but shows how you can easily make sure that the functions are callable with certain arguments, or have certain signatures.

Or you can put such expressions in a `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Cheers answer, but a bit more generic (works even if `Foo` doesn't contain a `T`):

```
template<typename...>
struct test {};

template<typename T>
using Foo_test = test<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()),
    decltype(std::declval<T>().bar())
>;

template<class T>
struct Foo : Foo_test<T> {
    // ...
};
```

This issue is related to *concepts* that are currently being designed for C++14, so probably such tests will be more convenient in the future.

Comment: This kind of test has the advantage that it works regardless of function result type, but the disadvantage of not being obvious at a glance. The test in my answer has the advantage of simple for the case at hand, but e.g. doesn't handle `void` function results (as written). I vacillated between presenting generic versus case-specific code, but chose the latter, adhering to the KISS principle.

Comment: @Cheers Ok, I was ready to edit my answer to make a bit even more generic, so I should probably stop :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code, I would simply use `static_assert` and `std::is_member_function_pointer` as below (documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer))

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::foo)>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::bar)>::value, "");
    T t;
    int foo() {
        return t.foo();
    }

    int bar() {
        return t.bar();
    }
};

struct baz {
    int foo() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<baz> x;
    return x.foo();
}
```